# Load values into a Struct from a Map in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Let's say I've a `map` with some user data:

```
iex(1)> user_map
#=> %{name: "Some User", email: "user@example.com", password: "*********"}
```

**How can I load this into a `%User{}` struct (hopefully using some Rubyish Elixir Magic)?**

---

I've currently tried these but all of them failed. Going through the [Structs](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html) section on Elixir website.

```
user_struct = %{ %User{} | user_map }
user_struct = %{ %User{} | Enum.to_list(user_map) }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the answer on the [`elixir-lang-talk`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/2xQqFOZSvk0) mailing list. We can use the [`struct/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2) method:

```
struct(User, user_map)
#=> %User{name: "Some User", email: "user@example.com", password: "*********"}
```

---

Another way, as mentioned by [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert), is to use [`Map.merge/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Map.html#merge/2):

```
Map.merge(%User{}, user_map)
#=> %User{name: "Some User", email: "user@example.com", password: "*********"}
```

caveat from the comments: **Map.merge cannot handle enforced keys on structs**

Comment: I think the first method should be preferred, Map.merge cannot handle enforced keys.

Comment: ^ very important distinction by @RusinaRange